# OpenMDAO add_desvar default lower bound

Tags: openmdao

If I do not specify a lower bound when defining a design variable via the *add_desvar* method, it looks like the default lower bound of the variable is set equal to *sys.float_info.min* (which on my machine is 2.2250738585072014e-308) (It looks like this is done at around line 330 in the file *openmdao/core/driver.py* of the distribution (1.5.0 Alpha)).

This can be seen by printing the results of *get_desvar_metadata()* after executing the Problem's *setup()* method.

The following is an example based on the *paraboloid_optimized_constrained.py* example provided by the distribution:

---

```
""" Constrained optimization of the paraboloid component."""

from __future__ import print_function

from openmdao.api import IndepVarComp, Component, Problem, Group, ExecComp, ScipyOptimizer
from openmdao.recorders.dump_recorder import DumpRecorder


class Paraboloid(Component):
    """ Evaluates the equation f(x,y) = (x-3)^2 + xy + (y+4)^2 - 3 """

    def __init__(self):
    super(Paraboloid, self).__init__()

    self.add_param('x', val=0.0)
    self.add_param('y', val=0.0)

    self.add_output('f_xy', val=0.0)

def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
    """f(x,y) = (x-3)^2 + xy + (y+4)^2 - 3"""

    x = params['x']
    y = params['y']

    unknowns['f_xy'] = (x-3.0)**2 + x*y + (y+4.0)**2 - 3.0

def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
    """ Jacobian for our paraboloid."""

    x = params['x']
    y = params['y']
    J = {}

    J['f_xy', 'x'] = 2.0*x - 6.0 + y
    J['f_xy', 'y'] = 2.0*y + 8.0 + x
    return J

if __name__ == "__main__":

    dr = DumpRecorder()
    top = Problem()

    root = top.root = Group()

    root.add('p1', IndepVarComp('x', 3.0))
    root.add('p2', IndepVarComp('y', -4.0))
    root.add('p', Paraboloid())

    # Constraint Equation
    root.add('con', ExecComp('c = x-y'))

    root.connect('p1.x', 'p.x')
    root.connect('p2.y', 'p.y')
    root.connect('p.x', 'con.x')
    root.connect('p.y', 'con.y')

    top.driver = ScipyOptimizer()

    top.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

    top.driver.add_recorder(dr)


    # top.driver.add_desvar('p1.x', lower=-50, upper=50)
    top.driver.add_desvar('p1.x')
    top.driver.add_desvar('p2.y', lower=-50, upper=50)
    top.driver.add_objective('p.f_xy')

    top.driver.add_constraint('con.c', lower=15.0, upper=1.0E99)

    top.setup()

    print( 'desvars_metadata = ', top.driver.get_desvar_metadata())

    top.run()

    print('\n')
    print('Minimum of %f found at (%f, %f)' % (top['p.f_xy'], top['p.x'], top['p.y']))

    print(' c = x-y = ', top['p.x'] - top['p.y'],   (top['p.x'] - top['p.y']) >= 15.0),  

    # Expected Output
    # Minimum of -27.083333 found at (7.166667, -7.833333)

pass
```

---

The result obtained from printing the design variables' meta data is

---

```
desvars_metadata =  OrderedDict([('p1.x', OrderedDict([('lower', 2.2250738585072014e-308), ('upper', 1.7976931348623157e+308), ('adder', 0.0), ('scaler', 1.0), ('size', 1)])), ('p2.y', OrderedDict([('lower', -50.0), ('upper', 50.0), ('adder', 0.0), ('scaler', 1.0), ('size', 1)]))])
```

---

In the python docs, *sys.float_info.min* is described as the "minimum positive normalized float" which is a very small positive number.  Shouldn't the default minimum bound be the largest negative float?  Can a design variable only be positive?  Could you help me understand what is happening here?

Thanks

---

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting this. You are right; this is a bug, and the fix you provide is the correct fix. I'll push up a fix today.